# Application name on Authorization page didn't change in 3-Legged auth

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

We changed our production application name and description by forge.autodesk.com/myapps. But on authorization page we still see the old one.
Can we force to refresh it somehow? 
Clearing browser cache didn't help. We've been wainting for 2 days but it still doesn't work.

Comment: this issue is currently under investigation by our Engineering and will update this answer once they get it sorted - in the meantime pls use a new app with the right name as a workaround

Comment: @BryanHuang any news?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got confirmation from Engineering that they've pushed the fix to production.

If you create a new app, the authorization page should show the name of the app properly. If you still want to use any impacted app, please edit and save the app.